# Why JPA creates tables in different place?

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb

In m project I'm using HSQLDB as a database and writing there by using JPA. All operations(write, read) are being done fine, but I can't find the tables. It is not under the schema. Where they can be?

Comment: What's the URL of the database that you gave to Hibernate? What's the URL of the database that you're looking at?

Comment: where can the log for your JPA provider be?

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html

Comment: if you're using it in-memory, there are no tables to be persisted, you know

Comment: yes I use in memory, but when I restart the Eclipse SELECT operation done fine and finds previously entered entries.

Comment: It seems it creates local file in workspace, but not under the schema folder